# Copying a file into multiple folders using Python

Tags: python, shutil

I have a file `Test.py`. I am pasting this file into 2 different folders as shown below but I also want to change `File=1` based on the folder it was pasted. For example, it is pasting `Test.py` into folders `1,2` with the same `File=1`. Instead, I want to paste `Test.py` into folders `1,2` with `File=1` and `File=2` respectively.

The content of `Test.py` is

```
File=1
```

The code I am using to paste is

```
import shutil
N=[1, 2]

src_path = r"C:\Users\USER\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Surfactant A-D\Multiple copy pasting\Test.py"
for i in N:
    dst_path = rf"C:\Users\USER\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Surfactant A-D\Multiple copy pasting\{i}"
    File={i}
    shutil.copy(src_path, dst_path)
    print('Copied')
```

Comment: The content of ```Test.py``` in folder ```1``` should read ```File=1``` and the content of ```Test.py``` in folder ```2``` should read ```File=2```. But the content of ```Test.py``` in folder ```2``` is still ```File=1.```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instruction File={i} has no effect on the **content** of the file you copy. To change this variable in the file, you must directly edit the text, the content, of the file.

To do so, you'll need a regex to detect the text you want to change. The expression that finds the text 'File=' followed by any number of digits is `r"File=\d*"`.

So instead of copying, what you need to do is:

- get the content of the file you want to copy
- find the expression and replace it
- create a new document with the value replaced.

Here is an example (you don't need shutil here):

```
import re

N=[1, 2]

pattern_to_replace = re.compile(r"File=\d*")  

src_path = r"C:\Users\USER\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Surfactant A-D\Multiple copy pasting\Test.py"

for i in N:

    # Get content of src file
    with open(src_path, 'r') as src:
        content = src.read()

    # Modify this content
    updated_content = re.sub(pattern_to_replace, f"File={i}", content)

    # Create the new file
    dst_path = rf"C:\Users\USER\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Surfactant A-D\Multiple copy pasting\{i}"
   with open(dst_path, 'w') as dst:
       dst.write(updated_content)

    print('Copied')
```